# Typegoose / Mongoose map custom type to db

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, typegoose

#### My setup

- Typescript
- Mongoose
- Typegoose

I have a class Timecode

```
export class Timecode {
  constructor(private timestamp: string) {}

  getAsMilliseconds(): number {
    throw new Error('Not implemented');
  }

  add(timecode: Timecode): Timecode {
    throw new Error('Not implemented');
  }

  toString(): string {
    return this.timestamp;
  }
}
```

and an entity Clip

```
import { prop } from '@typegoose/typegoose';
export class Clip extends BaseEntity {
  @prop({ required: true })
  name: string;

  @prop({ required: true })
  description: string;

  @prop({
    required: true,
    type: Timecode,
  })
  startTimecode: Timecode;
}
```

#### My question

Timecode can be serialised easily as a string by just saving its timestamp e.g `00:00:12:34`

I would like to be able to have `Timecode` properties on my entities and then when I save to mongo have them automatically serialised to string. Also they should be transformed back into Timecode instances when loaded.

Here is an example

```
const clip = new Clip();
clip.name = "My Clip"
clip.description = "My Dessciption"
clip.startTimecode = new Timecode("00:00:12:34")  
const savedClip = await ClipModel.create(clip)
const loadedClip = await ClipModel.findById(savedClip._id)
console.log(loadedClip.startTimecode.getAsMilliseconds()) //should work as startTimecode is an instance of Timecode
```

So I want mongoose to notice when I am saving an entity that has a property of type `Typecode` and convert it to a string and then reverse it to an instance of `Typecode` when loading.

Ideally I would be able to configure this in one place and not in every place where I declare a `Typecode` property.

Is this possible and how do I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use the `get` & `set` options to transform properties from / to `Timecode` and save it in the database as a string, but with multiple properties it can become tedious and hard to debug.

Mongoose also supports [Custom Schema Types](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/customschematypes.html) and Typegoose requires those types to have some properties (should have them by default), listed in [Custom Types](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/guides/advanced/custom-types).

A small example can be found in [typegoose's tests](https://github.com/typegoose/typegoose/blob/8a17683be064444b426d450fa46d65b7a2746ea7/test/tests/shouldRun.test.ts#L257-L287).